# Can I reference a standard c# class library in a Xamarin Forms application

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to setup a Visual Studio 2017 solution for a Xamarin Form application.  The application will run alongside an existing WinForms application.  The idea being that the client can choose any platform.  The WinForms app does all tasks whereas the Xamarain app will do a subset of tasks.

The Winforms app already has a data layer, service layer, presentation layer and a common POCO layer.

The Xamarin app will need to reference some of the POCO classes.

My idea was to somehow share the POCO classes between all projects.  Is this possible?  I am assuming I will need to create the POCO project as a portable class library however in all my tests I have failed.  I can reference the portable class library in the WinForms app and other layers but never in the Xamarin app.  I always get an error message saying the targets are different but for the life of me I cannot get them to be the same.

Has anyone achieved this?